# Как создать запрос sql с подсчетом за одного юзера?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица , в ней много столбцов но интересуют нас 2 , user_id и dolg_id
в dolg_id ищем цифру 45
надо узнать сколько у одного пользователя таких вот 45ок
например

`user_id  dolg_id
1            45
1            45
3            45
4            45`

и получить

```
1 = 2
3 = 1
4 = 1
```

p.s. mysql + бекенд на php

я выбираю сейчас SELECT * from table WHERE dolg_id=45
но это не обеденяет юзеров , а как посчитать вообще даже не догадываюсь

Comment: Count() и group by в помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже было сказано, используйте `COUNT` и `GROUP BY`. Пример, таблица:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    `user_id` INT,
    `dolg_id` INT
);

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1,30);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1,35);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (2,30);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (2,45);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (2,45);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (3,40);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (3,45);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (3,50);
```

Сам запрос:

```sql
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM table_name
WHERE dolg_id = 45
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Результат:

```
user_id  cnt  
      2    2
      3    1
```

Запустить [можно здесь](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74abff9/1/0).